# How to get data from keyboard for Basys2 FPGA using VHDL?

Tags: keyboard, vhdl, fpga

As the title suggests, how can we get data from keyboard to [Basys2](http://www.digilentinc.com/Products/Detail.cfm?Prod=BASYS2) FPGA using VHDL?

Comment: This is too general a question to get any answers.

Comment: I have no idea how can i do it, that is why I asked it. Can you provide a tutorial or any kind of information?

Comment: The first step is to research the PS/2 protocol. [Here is a random resource I found.](http://pcbheaven.com/wikipages/The_PS2_protocol/) You will need to build a serial receiver (similar to RS-232). What have you figured out so far?

Answer (score 1):

I am sure with board came some reference implementation - just look at it, how they did it. What you need, is how the PS/2 pin connect to the FPGA pins (I am sure that is in some kind of ucf File). Then you have the signals and you can do whatever you want with them.

As E.g. Andy already suggested, you should have a look at PS/2 protocol if you really want to bitbang it (I would assume in their reference design, they have just some softcore on the fpga and handle it more or less in software).